# My WEBDAV PROPFIND response isn't accepted by windows explorer

Tags: windows, webdav

I'm implementing a WebDAV server but am hitting a problem with the proposed client (Windows 7 explorer).  In windows I'm browsing to \server\public\container, which my server wants to present as a folder containing two files so I'm receiving the following request:

```
PROPFIND /public/container HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601
Depth: 1
translate: f
Content-Length: 0
Host: devsys:4511
```

My response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
Server: MyServer 2.12
Date: Mon, 08 Sep 14 17:57:50 -0000
Host: server.somewhere.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 2901

<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public/container</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:creationdate>2014-09-05T19:00:00Z</d:creationdate>
        <d:displayname>container</d:displayname>
        <d:resourcetype>
          <d:collection/>
        </d:resourcetype>
        <d:supportedlock>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:exclusive/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:shared/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
        </d:supportedlock>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public/container/myFile1</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getcontenttype>text/plain</d:getcontenttype>
        <d:getcontentlength>375</d:getcontentlength>
        <d:getetag>"1410198520"</d:getetag>
        <d:creationdate>2014-09-05T19:00:00Z</d:creationdate>
        <d:displayname>myFile1</d:displayname>
        <d:getlastmodified>05 Sep 2014 19:00:00 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype/>
        <d:supportedlock>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:exclusive/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:shared/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
        </d:supportedlock>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
  <d:response>
    <d:href>/public/container/myFile2</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:prop>
        <d:getcontenttype>text/plain</d:getcontenttype>
        <d:getcontentlength>375</d:getcontentlength>
        <d:getetag>"1410198523"</d:getetag>
        <d:creationdate>2014-09-05T19:00:00Z</d:creationdate>
        <d:displayname>myFile2</d:displayname>
        <d:getlastmodified>05 Sep 2014 19:00:00 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
        <d:resourcetype/>
        <d:supportedlock>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:exclusive/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
          <d:lockentry>
            <d:lockscope>
              <d:shared/>
            </d:lockscope>
            <d:locktype>
              <d:write/>
            </d:locktype>
          </d:lockentry>
        </d:supportedlock>
      </d:prop>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
```

> Windows kindly gives the error \myserver\public\container is not
>   accessible.  You might not have permission to use this network
>   resource.  Contact the administrator of the server to find out if you
>   have access permissions.
>        The parameter is incorrect.

It doesn't seem to give a clue what parameter it might be nor why it is incorrect.  Can anyone spot the glaring mistake?  Have I missed a property that Windows needs or have I simply done something wrong?

The server is in C so I have byte level control over the response.

Thanks - Rog

Comment: The syntax of d:getetag is broken (missing quoted), but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Being new to etags, I missed the bit about the quoting but I've changed that and no-go...  Thanks for spotting it though!

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation: test with multiple clients (such as Cyberduck).

The PROPFIND response above is incorrect; it has "multistatus" in no namespace, but it should be in the "DAV:" namespace.

Comment: Excellent spot - thanks!  However, I've fixed that (and edited the original post) but am still seeing the same problem.  I'll investigate cyberduck.

Comment: I've given cyberduck a try and it does show the folder with two files in it (once I'd quickly implemented 'HEAD', which it insisted upon requesting first).  The problem seems to be specific to Windows then unless CyberDuck is particularly lenient.

Comment: You might want to obtain a full network trace. Maybe it's not this request that is the cause. For instance, IIRC, the MS client might make request to parent folders up to "/".

Comment: It does request all sorts of other things but they're the parent folders, which I'm returning OK (I think, simply a container and it does seem to display the folder windows) and it looks for Desktop.ini and AutoRun.inf but I'm thinking failure to return those isn't going to worry it.

Answer (score 2):

After first removing most of the properties on the grounds that one of them was providing the 'incorrect parameter' then adding them back slowly, it seems that Windows didn't like the 'getlastmodified' date, which I had as:

05 Sep 2014 19:00:00 GMT

Changing it to:

Fri, 05 Sep 2014 19:00:00 GMT

Works lovely.

Thanks for all your help - it helped clean the code!